# Почему Error в java - unchecked?

Tags: java, исключения

Почему было бы плохо, если бы они были checked? Первое что пришло в голову, то что на этапе компиляции мы не можем предвидеть, что возникнет error во время выполнения программы. К тому же мы никак не можем повлиять на большинство событий Error. Но мне кажется, есть еще более существенны причины.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Почему было бы плохо, если бы они были checked?

Плохо было бы потому, что практически каждая функция может бросить практически любое исключение наследник Error, т.к. в большинстве случаев компилятор не сможет проверить, что функция, например, никогда не бросит `OutOfMemoryError` или `StackOverflowError`. Доказать это компилятор может далеко не во всех случаях.

А это значит, что если бы они были checked, то нужно объявлять их все в сигнатуре каждой функции.

Answer (score 0):

Дам кусочек [отсюда](https://habr.com/ru/company/golovachcourses/blog/225585/)

> Все исключительные ситуации делятся на «проверяемые» (checked) и
> «непроверяемые» (unchecked). Это свойство присуще «корневищу»
> (Throwable, Error, Exception, RuntimeException) и передается по
> наследству. Никак не видимо в исходном коде класса исключения.

> В дальнейших примера просто учтите, что

> — Throwable и Exception и все их наследники (за исключением наследников Error-а и RuntimeException-а) — checked

> — Error и RuntimeException и все их наследники — unchecked

checked exception = проверяемое исключение, проверяемое компилятором.

> Необходимо понимать, что
>
> — проверка на cheched исключения происходит в момент компиляции (compile-time checking)
>
> — перехват исключений (catch) происходит в момент выполнения (runtime checking)